# Remover linhas com menor frequência do pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Possuo um `dataframe` com mais de 13000 linhas e gostaria de remover algumas baseado na frequência com que aparecem levando em consideração a coluna nomeada `variedade`.

```py
df.variedade.value_counts()

RB867515    5084

SP813250    2500

RB855453     981

others       849

RB855156     750

RB855536     633

SP832847     561

RB835054     541

SP801842     423

SP835073     326

RB835486     253

RB845210     199

SP803280     187

RB72454      164

RB966928     146

Name: variedade, dtype: int64
```

Gostaria de manter apenas as 3 variedades que mais aparecem e apagar o restante, alterando assim a quantidade de linhas para pouco mais de 8000.

Tentei o comando:

```py
v = df[['variedade']]

df[v.replace(v.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)).gt(900).all(1)]
```

Entretanto, após pedir um `value_counts` da coluna `variedade` aparece que possuo mais de 13000 linhas ainda.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde estou errando?

Comment: Rafael, se minha resposta resolveu o seu problema, você pode marcar ela como aceita. Veja a importância disso no link [como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/30452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine o `value_counts` com um `head(3).index` para criar uma máscara com os elementos que mais aparecem no DataFrame. Após, com `isin` selecione eles.

```
mask = df['variedade'].value_counts().head(3).index    
df = df.loc[df['variedade'].isin(mask)]
```

Comment: Terry, tentei esse comando, entretanto após utilizar um `df.shape` ainda possuo mais de 13000 linhas... eu gostaria de sumir com as linhas que não correspondem àquelas 3 mais frequentes, mas isso não aconteceu.

Comment: Para que diminua o número de linhas no seu DF, você precisa atribuir o retorno do comando `.loc` a uma variável. Veja a edição da minha resposta :)

Comment: Valeu pela dica! Ajudou muito!!!

Comment: @RafaelMansini Se você aceitar minha resposta como a correta, também me ajuda :)